# Sequencing Data as 1,2,3 by account and product

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have SQL query that produces this output:

```
Acct   Product          Date
XXXX    RSP     2000-02-14 00:00:00.000
XXXX    TFSA    2012-04-05 00:00:00.000
XXXX    CASH    2000-02-14 00:00:00.000
YYYY    RSP     2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
YYYY    TFSA    2011-04-05 00:00:00.000
YYYY    CASH    2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

I want to be able to rename the date column like this:

```
Acct   Product     Date
XXXX    RSP          1
XXXX    TFSA         2
XXXX    CASH         1
YYYY    RSP          1
YYYY    TFSA         2
YYYY    CASH         1
```

Basically since the date of purchase of RSP and cash was the same and comes first i want it to be labelled 1, for the third product purchased, and since it was a data later on i want it to be labelled 2.

My query so far is:

```
With cte as(
Select Left(account,6) as 'CID',


            CASE  WHEN RIGHT(ACCT.ACCOUNT, 1) IN ('P', 'S', 'X', 'U', 'T') THEN 'RSP'                  
                  WHEN RIGHT(ACCT.ACCOUNT, 1) IN ('J', 'K') THEN 'TFSA'              
                  WHEN RIGHT(ACCT.ACCOUNT, 1) IN ('E', 'G', 'L', 'F', 'H', 'M') THEN 'MARGIN'               
                  WHEN RIGHT(ACCT.ACCOUNT, 1) IN ('A', 'B') THEN 'CASH'
                  WHEN RIGHT(ACCT.ACCOUNT, 1) IN ('V')        THEN 'RESP'
                  WHEN RIGHT(ACCT.ACCOUNT, 1) IN ('N')        THEN 'RDSP'
                  WHEN RIGHT(ACCT.ACCOUNT, 1) IN ('W' , 'V')   THEN 'SWEEP' 
            End as 'product',
Min(acct_open_date) as 'Date'
FROM WF_PM_ACCT_DB ACCT
WHERE Acct_Closing_Date IS NULL
GROUP BY LEFT(ACCOUNT,6), RIGHT(ACCT.ACCOUNT, 1)

)

select distinct CID, Product,
Min(date) as 'Date' from cte
group by CID, product
order by CID
```

Comment: SQL server managment studio 2012 and SQL server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Acct,Product,rn AS Date      
  FROM      
    (
       SELECT *,
              DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY Acct ORDER BY Date ) AS rn
         FROM WF_PM_ACCT_DB 
     ) Z;
```

Comment: That doesnt quite work. I've updated my question to reflect what i really need. i appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is limited. Use Dense rank function to assign the rank values. check the above answer.